# Unable to set back button on UINavigationController

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem, uinavigationitem

I'm presenting my view controller with the following code:

```
UINavigationController* navigation = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:sessionController];
[self presentViewController:navigation animated:YES completion:^{
}];
```

In the "viewDidLoad" method of my presented view controller I'm attempting to set the "back button" as follows:

```
UIBarButtonItem *newBackButton =
[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Test"
                                 style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
                                target:nil
                                action:nil];
[self.navigationController.navigationItem setBackBarButtonItem:newBackButton];
```

Silent failure, no exception, no log, no error, and NO button.  Any thoughts would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try:

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = newBackButton
```